# Flutter:Equivalent to NSLocale (iOS) & Locale (Android)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, locale, nslocale

I am trying to get ISOCountryCodes(list) from the phone system. I use `NSLocale.isoCountryCodes` in iOS native and `Locale.getISOCountries()` in the case of Android native. I am trying to do a new app in `Flutter` , was looking for the API for ISOCountries, couldnt find any in documentation.

Does Flutter has a similar API?

Comment: You could check the sources of the country pickers https://pub.dartlang.org/packages?q=country+codes

Comment: I checked a few of them eg:https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_country_picker , they have the data hardcoded in the source.... I dont want to do that...I just want system API to get the info

Comment: Is this available in Android as well? Usually it's preferred to have the same functionality on both platforms.

Comment: Yes In Android native I use  Locale.getISOCountries() its part of java.utils package i guess...this is the project https://github.com/anoop4real/WorldCountriesKotlin .... I was trying to convert the app to Flutter as part of my Flutter learning

Comment: If there is no such plugin it's probably a good idea to just create and publish one ;-)

Comment: :-) I think I am still to reach that stage...but anyway...Flutter SDK should expose that property(isoCountries..) from the underlying platforms to use it right?

Comment: Flutter does not expose much from the underlying platform by default. That's what plugins are for https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#developing-plugin-packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up in using [flutter_country_picker 0.1.1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_country_picker), I used a part of it where you have all the country meta data. Its still predefined data, anyways that was the quickest option.

Here is the source code [Country Search Flutter](https://github.com/anoop4real/CountrySearchFlutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can get isoCountryCode from [sim_info](https://pub.dev/packages/sim_info#-readme-tab-) plugin

A Flutter plugin for read SIM information. You can get SIM data for MCC, MNC, country code, etc...

This plugin is available iOS and Android platform